# How can iterate thru enumerated variables in bash?

Tags: bash

I have a set of variables, which I obtained thru `eval` a file.

My variables are named with this pattern:

```
variable_name_1
variable_name_2
...
variable_name_n
```

usually those variables contain a filename, so naturally I want to iterate with  in this nature:

```
for cur in variable_name_[i]; do
 <do stuff>; done
```

Is there a  way to achieve that functionality?

Comment: Why are you simulating arrays when `bash` supports them explicitly?

Comment: Because sometimes you can't do otherwise. The variables were given via a metadata file, which already has standardized structure. Next step is to cast it to true arrays.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, using [parameter expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html#AEN22568):

```
#!/bin/bash

variable_name_1="one"
variable_name_2="two"
variable_name_3="three"

for cur in ${!variable_name_*}; do
        echo "${cur}=${!cur}"
done
```

Example run:

```
$ ./foo.sh
variable_name_1=one
variable_name_2=two
variable_name_3=three
```

But you might want to reconsider how to obtain those variables, `eval`ing your "config file" (?) is probably not the best choice.